# How to display distance to a given location from current location in a tableview - Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, mapkit, cllocationmanager, cllocationdistance

Having some trouble trying to figure out the best way to go about this.

I have a tableView populated with custom cells that display events that are occurring. I can display the address for each of the venues and would like to display the distance from the users' current location to the venue address, in miles, in a label on an given UITableViewCell.

Not really sure on the best way to go about this, any guidance would be appreciated.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let lastLocation = locations.last
    let chester = CLLocation(latitude: 53.19, longitude: -2.89)
    let venueLoc = CLGeocoder();
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(post.venueAddress!) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error == nil {
            let placemark = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark

        }
    }

    let distanceInMeters = lastLocation?.distanceFromLocation(chester)
    let distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters! / 1609.34
    distanceFromLoc.text = "\(String(format: "%.1f", distanceInMiles)) mi"
```

You can see that I've been able to assign the correct string to my label but I am using given coordinates (chester), I cannot figure out how to take the geocodeAdressString function and use it correctly with the distance in meters line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, did you ever figure this out?  I have a pretty similar thing to resolve

Comment: Hey! I didn't not, came pretty close but was having some conversion issues.

Comment: I have managed to get mine sorted if you want to know how I did it?